# Proof of Iwasawa's theorem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I am reading Iwasawa's theorem from Washington's Cyclotomic Fields. The theorem goes as follows:
[image]

I do not understand the third line of the proof. Why is $\text{Gal}(L_n/K_n) \simeq A_n$?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $A_n$ is the name it gives to the $p$-sylow of $Cl(K_n)$ isomorphic to the Galois group by class field theory.